# Tail a file and execute a set of commands using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, tail

I'd like run `tail` on a log file and execute a set of commands once there is a match for a string in that log file. At the end of execution, the `tail` command should quit.

My attempt is shown below. It seems that any string found in the file is causing the `tail` to quit. If there is a match the set of commands will run and `tail` will exit as expected.

Why is `tail` quitting even when there is no match?

This is my command:

```
tail -f /logs/logfile.log | awk '/string_to_match/ { system("cp /s1/* /d1") }
                                                   {system("cp /s2/* /d2") } 
                                                   { system("cp /s3/* /d3") }      
                                                   { system("pkill tail") } '
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The way your awk is written, the second, third, fourth action blocks (the last being the `kill` command) will be executed for every line of input whether there is a match or not.

Comment: The `/string_to_match/` is only applied to `{ system("cp /s1/* /d1") }` All the other actions are executed for every line of the pipe including `{ system("pkill tail") }`

Comment: awk is for manipulating text, don't try to use it as a shell - that's just a terrible idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42406230/1745001 for a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

@MRE: Try:(We need not to mention so many system calls I think, though I haven't tested it at all).

```
tail -f /logs/logfile.log | 
awk '/string_to_match/ {
          system("cp /s1/* /d1; cp /s2/* /d2; cp /s3/* /d3; pkill tail") }'
```

Kindly try it once and let us know how it goes then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `awk` in current context,

```
grep -qs 'string_to_match' logs/logfile.txt && { 
   cp /s1/* /d1; cp /s2/* /d2; cp /s3/* /d3; pkill tail; 
}
```

**In your case**

```
tail -f logs/logfile.txt | grep -qs 'string_to_match' -  && { 
   cp /s1/* /d1; cp /s2/* /d2; cp /s3/* /d3; 
}
```

`pkill tail;` not required as `grep -q` exits after the first match

**Try**

In one tab

```
for i in {1..15}; do echo $i >> a; sleep 1; done
```

In another tab

```
tail -f a | grep -sq '3' && { echo found; echo done; }
```

**From Man**

> `-q`
>
> `--quiet`
>
> `--silent`
>
> Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.
>   Also see the -s or --no-messages option. (-q is specified by POSIX.)
>
> `-s`
>
> `--no-messages`
>
> Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files. Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not
>   conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like
>   GNU grep’s -q option.1 USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option
>   behaved like GNU grep’s. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q
>   and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null
>   instead. (-s is specified by POSIX.)

**For example**

Assume this is log

```
$ cat logfile 
1
2
3
4
somestring
a
a
s
a
```

for true

```
$ grep -qs 'somestring' logfile && { echo 'This';  echo 'test'; echo 'done, string found'; } || echo 'not found'
This
test
done, string found
```

for false

```
$ grep -qs 'test' logfile && { echo 'This';  echo 'test'; echo 'done, string found'; } || echo 'not found'
not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your awk is written, the second, third, fourth action blocks (the last being the kill command) will be executed for every line of input whether there is a match or not.

Assuming all the commands should be run based on the one string-to-match,
it sounds like you want instead:

```
tail -f /logs/logfile.log | awk '/string_to_match/ {system("cp /s1/* /d1")
                                                    system("cp /s2/* /d2") 
                                                    system("cp /s3/* /d3")     
                                                    system("pkill tail") }'
```